# EF Core entity inheritance from different sources without discriminator

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to configure the two entities shown below with EF Core:

**User:**

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FriendlyIdentifier
    {
        get
        {
            var name = $"{Name} {Surname}";
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                return name;
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email))
                return Email;
            else
                return UserId.ToString();
        }
    }

    public ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}
```

**UserDetails:**

```
public class UserDetails : User
{
    public DateTime? LatestBookingDate { get; set; }
}
```

The reason for this is that I want to be able to pull users with their latest booking date without having to pull all the booking and then determine the latest booking date manually in code. To achieve this I have created a SQL view which selects the latest booking date and I want to bind `UserDetails` to this view.

I have the following EF setup:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(builder =>
{
    builder.ToTable("userdetails");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.UserId);
    builder.HasIndex(x => new { x.Name, x.Surname, x.Email });
});

modelBuilder.Query<UserDetails>()
    .ToView("view_userdetails");
```

But this gives the following error when trying to select a `UserDetails` entity:

> 'Cannot set 'User' as the base type of 'UserDetails'. Inheritance
>   hierarchies cannot contain a mix of entity types and query types.'

I am aware that there is a `HasDiscriminator` extension as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/inheritance but I don't really have a discriminator as `UserDetails` is just an extension of `User`.

Is there any way for me to get this working? I don't really want to duplicate the properties of `User` into `UserDetails` because then there's two entities to maintain when anything changes. I would like to retain the inheritance.

Comment: Maybe you can add `LatestBookingDate` to the `userdetails` table as a computed column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would like to retain the inheritance.

You can't (at least not in the way it is now). That's clearly indicated by the exception message - it says "cannot contain a mix" and does not provide you a suggestion.

What you can do is to move your current `User` class members to a new base *non entity*, *non query* type class and let both `User` entity and `UserDetails` query type inherit from it, e.g.:

```
public abstract class UserInfo
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FriendlyIdentifier
    {
        get
        {
            var name = $"{Name} {Surname}";
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
                return name;
            else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email))
                return Email;
            else
                return UserId.ToString();
        }
    }

    public ICollection<Booking> Bookings { get; set; }
}

public class User : UserInfo { }

public class UserDetails : UserInfo
{
    public DateTime? LatestBookingDate { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow you to maintain the common model in a single place. The drawback is that `UserDetails` will not be able to be used in a places which expect `User`, and has to be converted (although since all common properties are the same, it should be trivial "auto" task for AutoMapper).

Please note that this solution requires you to `Ignore` the `Bookings` navigation property in the query type:

```
modelBuilder.Query<UserDetails>(builder =>
{ 
    builder.ToView("view_userdetails");
    builder.Ignore(e => e.Bookings);
});
```

or move it to the `User` entity.

Comment: Thanks @ivan. That's a pretty reasonable solution. I might have to make a few changes in my services so they take `UserInfo` instead of `User` as a parameter but it's not the end of the world.